# Network Manager connection is unmanageable until I disable and enable networking

Tags: 12.10, network-manager

Ubuntu 12.10. The problem is: I've created DSL connection accessible for all users and made it to connect automatically. It works okay.

The problem is, when I log in to my session, I cannot control it. The only option Network Manager provides is to enable/disable network management. I can't connect or disconnect to that DSL connection, I can't enable my VPN connections.

However, if I disable and then enable again network management, I see all options: both control for DSL and VPN connections.

In all previous Ubuntu versions I had no problem with this.